# xdebug is skipping lines while debugging

Tags: php, eclipse, debugging, xdebug

Using Eclipse/xdebug n Windows 2008 server.  Yesterday I was able to successfully debug one php file.  Today, with a very similar php file, it is skipping lines and then going off into oblivion.
Code snippet:

```
//$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = '[{"ARDivisionNo":"01","CustomerNo":"ABF","ContactCode":"ARTIE   JOHN","CustomerName":"American Business Futures","fname":"Artie ","lname":"Johnson","EmailAddress":"philmcintosh@comcast.net","Billing_Address1":"2131 N. 14th Street","Billing_Address2":"Suite 105","Billing_Address3":"Accounting Department","Billing_City":"Irvine","Billing_State":"CA","Billing_Zip":"92618","UDF_FC_ENABLED":"Y","UDF_FC_CUSTOMERID":2.0,"UDF_FC_ADDRESS_BOOK_ID":3.0,"TelephoneNo1":"","FaxNo":""}]'; 
$json = json_decode($data, true);

Foreach ($json as $i => $row) {
    $customers_id = tep_db_prepare_input($row['UDF_FC_CUSTOMERID']);
    $customers_firstname = tep_db_prepare_input($row['fname']);
```

(I pasted in the json for debugging purposes - this worked yesterday in the other file.)
In this file, the first strange thing is the debugger actually stops on the commented out "$data = file_get_contents('php://input');" line.
The after the next "$data =" line, it skips to "$customers_id =" line.  At this point $data shows as empty in the variables window.
Any ideas on what is wrong/how to fix?

Answer (score 2):

It is likely that Xdebug seems a different file of source code than that you think you see. Are you sure you have saved the file first before starting to debug?

There are a few cases where Xdebug does skip lines as it doesn't see any breakpoints. This is because PHP itself doesn't always give this possibility. It is often on if/else statements without { and } only though. In order to find out what is going on, you can make a remote debugging log by adding to php.ini:

```
xdebug.remote_log=/tmp/xdebug.log
```

Xdebug will write all communication packets into this log for you to look at. Perhaps that gives a clue.